# Add Icon to Footer

Tags: html, icons, footer

How do I add the icon to the footer? Here is the following code I have completed.

CSS:

```
#footer {
    padding: 0 10px;
    background:#EEE;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    left:0px;
    position:fixed;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;

    }
    #footer p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<div id="footer">
    <p><center>2013 - Index</center>
    <img style="text-align:right" src="./images/ranbir.jpg"  height="25" width="25"></p>
</div>
```

Thank you for any help!

I am trying to put the 2013 - Index in the center and the icons goes right. But it doesn't seem right at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try either:

```
<img style="float:right" src="./images/ranbir.jpg"  height="25" width="25"></p>
```

or

```
<img style="position:absolute; right:0;" src="./images/ranbir.jpg"  height="25" width="25"></p>
```

Let me know if that helps you and have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/s89s7 if you want to see it working.

Edit: To clarify, text-align only works on things inside that element. E.g.

```
<body>
    <p style="text-align:center">Text</p>
</body>
```

Will align "Text" inside of "p" but *will not* align "p" inside of "body". Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you it works. How would I make the icon go up a litte, same line as the text? you know what I mean? @joshhunt

Comment: I would recommend using position:absolute, that way you can control it and make it go wherever you want it to go by using using top, bottom, left, and right. E.g.
<img style="position:absolute;right:0px;top:20px;" src="http://www.destil.cz/images/stackoverflow.png"  height="25" width="25">
Have a look at the updated fiddle.